# Calculating the number of messages sent in a period

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Using the Messaging API in Android, is it possible to query the number of messages sent during a particular period - say 1 month?

I am not sure if using a BroadcastReceiver for the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT` event would be supported from Android 4.4 and up. I think this is the best approach as the first method will not be able to count if the user deletes some messages.

Can anyone give a better solution or if the first one I mentioned is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Access the content provider

There is a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for accessing SMS messages, but it's not documented in the public SDK. If you use [`ContentResolver.query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String)) with a `Uri` of `content://sms` you should be able to access these messages.

You can find more information [on this Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/2e049e79f88d95d5) or [previous questions on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+sms).

Comment: I believe that there is a "content://sms/sent" specifically for sent messages. Is it possible to query this table so as to get the count for a period?

Comment: Yes, you can query this in multiple ways. Actual code is given in the links.